# Generic interface with none generic object argument

Tags: c#, oop, interface

How can I make my Repositories have a *generic interface* with a search method that take *different* types as arguments?

I tried to give my interface this property:

```
 Task<IEnumerable<T>> Search(object Query, int? limit);
```

For example *UsersController* want to send *SearchUserQuery* (properties id, name, and phoneNumber) as argument when using `IRepository<User>`. But *CompanyController* need to send *SearchCompanyQuery* (with properties guid, name, Taxnumber) as argument when using the `IRepository<Company>`.

**The Problem**

When I add the Search method to a repository (see example below) it won't recognize SearchUserQuery as an object, and give me Compile error.

```
 Task<IEnumerable<User>> Search(SearchUserQuery query, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementing method much match the interface signature *exactly*.

If the queries are different, this must be reflected in the interface:

```
interface IRepository<T, TQuery>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> Search(TQuery query, int? limit);
}
```

Then your implementation:

```
class UserRepository : IRepository<User, SearchUserQuery>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<User>> Search(SearchUserQuery query, int? limit) // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a great answer!